# SQLite .dump command from SQLiteConnection object

Tags: c#, sqlite

Using SQLite from .net, Is there a way to access the `.dump` command or something equivalent from the SQLiteConnection class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.dump` command is part of the sqlite command line program (`shell.c`), not part of the sqlite library. So, it is unlikely to be provided by a .net connection class.

However, since the source code for the sqlite command line program is in the public domain, and uses the same library as the .net wrapper, it would be possible to translate the C code for the `.dump` command to C#. See the function `do_meta_command` in [this file](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/rlog?f=sqlite/src/shell.c).