# System.Data.SQLite equivalent of .dump

Tags: c#, sqlite, dump

I'm trying to figure out the equivalent of the SQLite `.dump` command using the `System.Data.SQLite` dll in C#. I know I can do this manually by getting a list of tables/values and creating the inserts, but I was hoping for a better way.

Actually, if you know of a way to do any of the other commands (from .help) using C# that would be awesome. I'm implementing many of them manually now and it's not fun.

Comment: possible duplicates of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332440/sqlite-dump-command-from-sqliteconnection-object and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211717/how-to-dump-sqlite-in-memory-database-into-file-with-ado-net

Comment: also, for the OP, what have you tried? I did a quick google search and found those 2 questions as the first few hits.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I've been searching for hours and didn't come across those. I knew a few of the SQLite commands had easy equivalents (like .schema and .tables) but I wasn't sure about .dump. I'll just implement the GUI relevant ones manually.